Sort only few columns in pandas dataframe by month and year
How do I sort the only the month year columns in below dataframe?  These columns could differ for different stock.




Quarterly Results
Stockname
Mar 2021
Jun 2021
Sep 2021
Dec 2021
Dec 2022
Mar 2023
Jun 2023
Sep 2023
Mar 2022
Jun 2022
Sep 2022




0
Sales
526433
40.8
41.64
47.7
47.62
54.14
51.94
50.95
50.39
54.71
50.92
63.42


1
Expenses
526433
36.78
36.7
39.98
42.3
48.94
49.74
48.58
48.46
51.69
45.54
57.43


2
Operating Profit
526433
4.02
4.94
7.72
5.32
5.2
2.2
2.37
1.93
3.02
5.38
5.99


3
OPM %
526433
9.85%
11.86%
16.18%
11.17%
9.60%
4.24%
4.65%
3.83%
5.52%
10.57%
9.44%


4
Other Income
526433
0.7
0.5
0.35
3.89
2.74
1.55
1.98
0.42
2.19
2.43
1.58




I tried to refer this answer, but Its not selective. Hence getting error: DateParseError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: Quarterly Results, at position 0 

Code
Assign variable date as the date that precedes the date in the columns, using the following code
date = '1970-01-01'
out = df.sort_index(
    axis=1, 
    key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce', format='mixed').fillna(date)
)

out


Example Code
import pandas as pd
data = {'Quarterly Results': ['Sales', 'Expenses', 'Operating Profit', 'OPM %', 'Other Income'], 'Stockname': [526433, 526433, 526433, 526433, 526433], 'Mar 2021': ['40.8', '36.78', '4.02', '9.85%', '0.7'], 'Jun 2021': ['41.64', '36.7', '4.94', '11.86%', '0.5'], 'Sep 2021': ['47.7', '39.98', '7.72', '16.18%', '0.35'], 'Dec 2021': ['47.62', '42.3', '5.32', '11.17%', '3.89'], 'Dec 2022': ['54.14', '48.94', '5.2', '9.60%', '2.74'], 'Mar 2023': ['51.94', '49.74', '2.2', '4.24%', '1.55'], 'Jun 2023': ['50.95', '48.58', '2.37', '4.65%', '1.98'], 'Sep 2023': ['50.39', '48.46', '1.93', '3.83%', '0.42'], 'Mar 2022': ['54.71', '51.69', '3.02', '5.52%', '2.19'], 'Jun 2022': ['50.92', '45.54', '5.38', '10.57%', '2.43'], 'Sep 2022': ['63.42', '57.43', '5.99', '9.44%', '1.58']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Quarterly Results': ['Sales', 'Expenses', 'Operating Profit', 'OPM %', 'Other Income'],
    'Stockname': [526433] * 5,
    'Mar 1990': [40.8, 36.78, 4.02, '9.85%', 0.7],
    'Jun 1990': [41.64, 36.7, 4.94, '11.86%', 0.5],
    'Sep 1990': [47.7, 39.98, 7.72, '16.18%', 0.35],
    'Dec 1990': [47.62, 42.3, 5.32, '11.17%', 3.89],
    'Dec 1991': [54.14, 48.94, 5.2, '9.60%', 2.74],
    'Mar 1992': [51.94, 49.74, 2.2, '4.24%', 1.55],
    'Jun 1992': [50.95, 48.58, 2.37, '4.65%', 1.98],
    'Sep 1992': [50.39, 48.46, 1.93, '3.83%', 0.42],
    'Mar 1991': [54.71, 51.69, 3.02, '5.52%', 2.19],
    'Jun 1991': [50.92, 45.54, 5.38, '10.57%', 2.43],
    'Sep 1991': [63.42, 57.43, 5.99, '9.44%', 1.58]
})
print(df.to_string())

# One-liner to sort month-year columns
df = df[['Quarterly Results', 'Stockname'] +
         sorted(df.columns[2:], key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%b %Y'))]

print(df.to_string())

